# Printing the output of _mm_cmpeq_epi8 (__m128i type)

Tags: c++, sse, simd

[Herein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313646/fast-counting-the-number-of-equal-bytes-between-two-arrays) a nice method for comparing two arrays of character is suggested (the accepted answer).

The output of `vs`and `vt` can be printed to the screen with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257166/print-a-m128i-variable) but results of comparisons `v` are weird (four zeros and random numbers).

Comment: Note that if you happen to be using OS X then the Apple builds of gcc and clang have extensions to printf for printing SIMD vectors, which makes life a lot easier. Unfortunately I don't think these extensions have made it onto other platforms (yet ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want print the content of __m128i vector to screen you might use something like this:

```
template<class T> inline void Log(const T * data, size_t size, const std::string & name)
{
    std::cout << name << " = { ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << int(data[i]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "} " << std::endl;
}

inline void LogU8(const __m128i & value, const std::string & name)
{
    uint8_t buffer[16];
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)buffer, value);
    Log(buffer, 16, name);
}
```

Comment: What is the header for _mm_storeu_si128?

Comment: #include <emmintrin.h>